# How to send liker scale question type using adaptive card to ms teams. And get the answers back from it?

Tags: adaptive-cards

Can anyone provide any sample. And how can we get the answers back to the bot. (Using adaptive cards)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs on [adaptive cards for bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/bots) and [rich cards in bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-add-rich-cards?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). All you really need to do is to add a button to your card for each option on your Likert scale and then record which one the user clicks on, as you would the response to any other button.

Comment: But we won't need buttons for each option right? we can have dropdowns for each row questions. And when user clicks on submit once we've to send all the row options to bot.

Comment: You can design your interface and write the code to support it however you want.